# How to search splunk query which includes double quotes in the string to search

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to search for a pattern(see below) in the logs using splunk. The String which I am going to search includes double quotes.

Below info log is printed in the logger..

```
INFO: o.l.k.SomeClass: {"function": "delete", "tenenId":"15897",.......}
```

And the string i want to search is
**"function": "delete"**

The splunk query I am trying to execute is.,

```
index="12585" "\"function\": \"delete\""
```

I am not quite sure if this is going to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are probably multiple whitespace characters between `function`and `delete`. I suggest you just search for the two phrases separately, rather than together

```
index="12585" \"function\": \"delete\"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in raw format, you can look if the "function" field is automatically extracted by Splunk. If yes, you can simply search for `index="index_1" function="delete"` else, you can search for `index="index_1" "function" "delete"` as is, and Splunk will search for function and delete in your raw event.

Answer (score 0):

I was researching for a similar problem where I need to search for exact string match which includes double quotes. It doesn't look like we can directly query with escaped double quote. So we have to use `regex`.

In your scenario, you could try this query:

```
index="12585" | regex fieldname=".*\"function\": \"delete\".*"
```

It will try to run regex match on the fieldname. The regex can be validated in any online regex tester.
I haven't figured out how to query with _raw field. Doing `_raw=".*\\\"delete\\\".*"` doesn't seem to be returning anything..